# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target SALESFORCE

Tags: salesforce, apex

I've got an error when I call API

> FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Can anybody explain this error?

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote that is producing this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs.
When sending outbound messages, delegated authentication requests or Apex callouts to secure/SSL endpoints (e.g. https://myintegration.acme.com), a Salesforce.com organization (acting as the client) will only trust the target host (that will act as the server) if this presents a certificate signed by a root Certification Authority (CA) included in the list shown in the below link. In other words, in this scenario self-signed certificates are not allowed to be used by the target host.

Please see link below.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326722&type=1&mode=1